# Xamarin forms how to make a graphical custom UI component

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm learning Xamarin (Forms) at the moment and I want to create a special component for my app so I'm looking for some guidance to get me started.

I'm imagining a component which has a main button in the middle, with text that could be "Birds" followed by the number of birds spotted this week.

Then, for each species spotted this week, there would be a line leading to the species name and the aggregated number of how many of that species have been spotted (so x number of lines). Basically a kind of a grouping diagram which acts like buttons.

I drew it up in mspaint, just without numbers.

[image: Mock-up of the component]

I imagine my first step working with Xamarin Forms is to create the component in both Android Studio and Xcode, then package it as an component.

Can my idea be done in both Android and iOS? If so, would you please provide some tutorials on creating something like it, because I haven't come across something that I can use to get started yet.

UPDATE: SkiaSharp looks like the way I should be going.. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/introduction/

Answer (score -1):

Xamarin allows you to build mobile apps completely in C# so you don't need native development tools (like Android Studio and Xcode) all development can be done completely in [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) (Mac or PC).

You can totally make what you're describing with [Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms)! In order for you to do it, you must make a Custom Render. See [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) on Xamarin's website for making a custom renderer.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I've already been by that page you are referring to, but I understand Custom render as taking an exsisting component and altering it. In that case, non of the components I know of sort of matches my requirement..

Comment: @RachelBual You can start from scratch by using a `View` as the base for your Custom Renderer. See [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/) article for instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Okay I'll look into that and update this thread with my findings and accept if that turns out to be the way to go.

Comment: Just scraped google for custom renderers, but I can only find tutorials which makes a button look different. But that is a start i guess. Problem is I can't imagine how to get x of those buttons drawn in a circle and also how to draw lines between them. If you could point out an tutorial where they do these more advanced things in the direction im heading? I still intent to read your link about creating a view, but it just looks kind of generel by first look.

Comment: @RachelBual If you edit your question to reflect your new questions, I can edit my answer to better answer you. You are going to be looking at some fairly advanced code to layout your buttons and draw lines. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662340/dynamically-arrange-imagebuttons-around-a-circle-in-android) could possibly help you with that part.